# Accessing data out of parent controller with Controller as

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am working through the book Learning Angular Js by Brad Dayley.  The book uses `$scope` in its examples.  I am pushing myself to use `controllerAs`.  In chapter seven the book focuses on creating custom directives.

I created a simple one similar to the example provided. Inside I am setting transclude to true.  I am using the link function to append a footer to the parent div.  Inside of the footer tag the author of the book  calls `scope.$parent.title`  In the example the `title` value comes from the parent controller.

```
  .directive('myBox', function() {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {title: '@', bwidth: '@bwidth'},
            template: "<div><span class='titleBar'>{{title}}"+ "</span> <div ng-transclude></div></div>",
            link:function(scope, elem, attr, controller, transclude) {
                console.log('scope', scope.$parent)
                console.log('controller', controller);
                elem.append('<span class="footer">'+ scope.$parent.title + '</span>');
                elem.css('border', '2px ridge black');
                elem.css('display', 'block');
                elem.css('width', scope.bwidth);
            }
        }
    })
```

Inside of the book the controller uses `$scope`, I wanted to use `controller as` and am using `vm` to equal this.  Here is my function for the controller.  The `vm.title` is supposed to be the value on the footer.

I am getting `undefined` from my console when I check the value.

```
function FunCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.title = "myApplication";
}
```

Here is a plunker of what I am trying

http://plnkr.co/edit/uUeKrTwLOfkcGpkTU1Uz?p=preview

Comment: Can you provide a complete example showing your problem?

Comment: Here is a basic plunker   http://plnkr.co/edit/uUeKrTwLOfkcGpkTU1Uz?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you use **ng-controller** syntax, it's just calling the members of the controller like "start()" in the scope.

---

```
   <input ng-click="start()" type="button" value="Button"/>
```

---

- But when you use **controllerAs** syntax, an instance of the controller is created and assigned to the reference variable that you have provided - "fun". So whatever you have defined in the controller is accessible only by using the reference. - "fun.start()" in the scope.

---

```
   <input ng-click="fun.start()" type="button" value="Button"/>
```

---

Therefore you have to do the same when accessing the parent scope members if you have used **controllerAs** syntax like shown below

```
scope.$parent.fun.title
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hplEMfl3g7qZHSLIIKBV)

**Note**
*The controller you are outputting in console is the one that belongs to the directive which you have not defined.*